# Calculate Histogram opencv from C++ to java

Tags: java, android, c++, opencv, histogram

Here is the C++ that i am trying to implement in android

```
if (frame.channels()==3) cvtColor(frame,frame,CV_BGR2GRAY);
/// Establish the number of bins
int histSize = 256;
/// Set the ranges ( for B,G,R) )
float range[] = { 0, 256 } ;
const float* histRange = { range };
bool uniform = true; bool accumulate = false;
/// Compute the histograms:
calcHist( &frame, 1, 0, Mat(), hist, 1, &histSize, &histRange, uniform, accumulate );
hist /= frame.total();

Mat logP;
cv::log(hist,logP);

float entropy = -1*sum(hist.mul(logP)).val[0];

cout << entropy << endl;
```

and so java so far

```
public float histogramEntropy(Mat mat) {

if (mat.channels()==3) Imgproc.cvtColor(mat,mat,Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2GRAY,3);

MatOfInt histSize = new MatOfInt(256);    
final MatOfFloat histRange = new MatOfFloat(0f, 256f);

Boolean uniform = true; Boolean accumulate = false;   
Mat hist = new Mat();
```

> //Cannot resolve Method here

```
Imgproc.calcHist( mat, 1, 0,new Mat(), hist, 1, histSize, histRange, uniform, accumulate );
```

> Incompatible type found long (but according to the document "hist" should be mat [here](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/histograms.html?highlight=calchist#calchist) )

```
hist /= mat.total();

Mat logP;
```

> Cannot find natural log implementation with opencv and java

```
cv::log(hist,logP);
```

> finally the "sum" function from C++. Is there any easy implementation in java ?

```
float entropy = -1*sum(hist.mul(logP)).val[0];

return entropy;
}
```

there is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34232349/opencv-c-calchist-to-java) which says to change the input mat to CV_32F type Even still i am unable resolve these issues.

Thanks in advance

Comment: In the c++ code histSize is just a int and in the java code you define it as MatofInt instead of just a int

Comment: Hey,Thanks for ur quick reply. i tried it but still change

Comment: *no changes in the error